# SQL - Concatenation without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have two tables (A and B) which do not share primary keys. I need some kind of concatenation in which for each row in Table A **I have to add Table B rows if date_B < date_A**.

*date format: yyyy-mm-dd

Table A

```
+-------+-----+-----------+
| id_A  | op_A|   date_A  |
+-------+-----+-----------+
| 1     |  0  | 2018-10-01|
| 2     |  0  | 2018-12-31| 
+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Table B

```
+-----+--------+-------------+
| id_b| other  |  date_B     |
+-----+--------+-------------+
| a   |  8     | 2018-09-01  |
| b   |  90    | 2018-12-01  | 
+-----+--------+-------------+
```

Correct Result:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-----+--------+-------------+
| id_A| op_A|   date_A  | id_B| other  |  date_B     |
+-----+-----+-----------+-----+--------+-------------+
| 1   |  0  | 2018-10-01| a   |  8     | 2018-09-01  |
| 2   |  0  | 2018-12-31| a   |  8     | 2018-09-01  |
| 2   |  0  | 2018-12-31| b   |  90    | 2018-12-01  |  
+-----+-----+-----------+-----+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.date_B < a.date_A
```

Output:

```
id_A    op_A    date_A      id_b    other   date_B
1       0       2018-10-01  a       8       2018-09-01
2       0       2018-12-31  a       8       2018-09-01
2       0       2018-12-31  b       90      2018-12-01
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ea0518/1)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!